# G+ API HTTPError 400

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-plus

I am trying to make a request from the G+ API in order to populate a list of userIDs based on a text post query.  I am using a while loop to work through the returned list of users and after a while I get a HTTPError 400.  I believe this is due to the JSON property of nextPageToken not existing at the very bottom of the return stack.  My problem (I think) is that I have tried several strategies of ending the loop but no matter what, the loop executes one too many times and gives me a bad request error.  What am I supposed to look for to successfully end the loop? 
I used a very similar technique at a different point in my code and that worked fine but this does not for whatever reason.

My code that doesn't work:

```
request = activities_resource.search(\
                                     maxResults=20, orderBy='best', query= query_in)
while request is not None:
    activities_document = request.execute(http=http)
    request = activities_resource.list_next(request, activities_document)
```

Very similar code that works fine:

```
request = activities_resource.list(userId= id, collection = 'public', maxResults = '100' )

while request is not None: #forms a loop until we hit the bottom of a users timeline
    activities_document = request.execute(http=http)
    request = activities_resource.list_next(request, activities_document)  #creates next page token
```

Comment: The two pieces of code may be similar in appearance, but are actually totally different. The working code tests `while request` where `request` is `activities_resource.list_next(...)` -- You're testing `activities_document['nextPageToken']` where `activities_dcoument` is `activities_resource.search(...)` If you have code that's functional, what's the objective you're trying to get at?

Comment: The first snippet is for creating a list of user IDs based off a query, the second is working through each of those user's ids and grabbing their entire timeline. Each loop works through the list using the pageTokens. I tried changing the code to function exactly like the second bit and it still gave me the same error.